# With webflux is there a way for 2 or more separate applications to publish to the same flux

Tags: spring-webflux

I have several applications working together. There's a UI app with a `@RestController` and `@GetMapping` endpoints that return `Sinks.Many.asFlux()` populated in the background as a `Sinks.many().multicast().onBackpressureBuffer()` message sink that publishes `sink.tryEmitNext` strings back to the rest controller. The code looks like this:

```
@RestController
public class Test {
  @Autowired
  TestService testService;

  @GetMapping(value = "/test1", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
  public Flux<String> test1() {
    List<Event> list1 = setupList();
    Logs.Info("Out test1ListOfSize1");
    return testService.runTest1(list1);
  }
}
```

The `testService.runTest1` method looks like this:

```
@Autowired
MySink mySink;

public Flux<String> runTest1(List<Event> list1) {
    issueResponse.run(list1);
    return mySink.theSink().asFlux();
}
```

The `issueResponse.run` is a thread that populates the `MySink` class with strings from various events going on in the application using `tryEmitNext` like this:

```
@Component
public class MySink {

  Sinks.Many<String> sink;

  public void next(String event) {
    sink.tryEmitNext(event);
  }
}
```

Many other threads in the application also call the `MySink` as `mySink.next("show event")` and feed string events back to the rest controller that are displayed on the browser in real time.

Now I want other applications to feed events back to the same flux on the browser, while it's active. Like an externally connectable flux or connectable sink. How can I expose the UI flux to other applications (over the network) to go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An optimal solution would be to expose a new endpoint responsible for receiving the data from the other applications and emitting them to your current Sink.